# Inherited font-size not working inside paragraph in Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, inheritance, font-size

I have `<code>` inside `<p>` in a Wordrpess blog. And I set the font size of `<code>` to `inherit`, in order to have the same size of parent `<p>`.

[image: font-size of code tag is about 14px]
However, font-size of `<code>` is still about 14px...

[image: font-size of p tag is about 18px]
...which is still different from 18px font-size of parent `<p>`.

You can see the [demo post](http://chenghuayang.com/blog/love-lorem-ipsum/#more-7). Is there any wrong setting I did on it?

**Update**: I've made `font-size: inherit` to `font-size: 1.1em` so to match the general size of paragraph. You can switch back to the former one to check my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the `<code>` element is special, the browser default style is `13px` font size and `monospace` font family. It doesn't quite follow the normal CSS rules, similarly to replaced elements like `<input>`, `<textarea>` etc.

Set a fixed size `code{font-size:18px;}` or so, if you need to.

Further reading:

- http://galjot.si/element-code-and-font-size
- http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2010/02/12/fixed-monospace-sizing/
- http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/rendering.html#replaced-elements

Comment: You're right. The result is actually 14.625px, which is from 13px(browser default size) X 62.5%(my resetting) X 1.8em (`<p>` font sizing).

Comment: Since `<p>` is normally 18px, and 16px in small display, do you any idea about making `<code>` responsive, too? :)

Comment: it can be very easy if you use media queries.

Comment: Sure. My try is to make `<code>` time the ratio 16px/13px (p/code tag), so that it's the same as `<p>`, and this does not need media queries. But don't know if it's good to make the font sizes of these two the same or not.

Comment: For me it's not necessary to make the font size of code exactly the same as p tag, it looks nicer when it's slightly smaller.

Comment: I just got one more question. Does the `inherit` of `<code>` not have the same styling from its parent? Well, what I mean is that inherit will not inherit all styling from its parent tag, but have its own styling?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that, most of time you won't need to set up property `inherit`, it gets inherited styles automatically.

Comment: I mean that why the child not having the same `font-size` as its parent even if I set it to `inherit`? It's weird they are not the same, and can be affected by the browser's default setting.

Comment: Because of the special elements like `code`, most of the elements do follow the rules.

Answer (score 0):

The browser reduces the default font size by a percentage for the `<code>` element. In order to reset that application:

```
code{
  font-size: 1em;
}
```

This answer sets the code font-size to whatever the default browser setting is, 16px is usually the default.

http://code.stephenmorley.org/html-and-css/fixing-browsers-broken-monospace-font-handling/

Comment: Good idea. But now my problem is that I have multiple setting for `<p>` like 62.5% and 1.8em to make it 18px, and how to make `<code>` responsive. :)

Comment: I totally understand how engaging ems and pxs at the same time could be heart-breaking. There is plenty of literature out there, some old and some newer, in regards to how exactly we should treat sizing units.  One of my favorites and something very close to how I program for personal use: http://csswizardry.com/2011/12/measuring-and-sizing-uis-2011-style/